# Character cloth moving strange to use weight bone

Tags: armature, bones, blender-internal-render-engine, weight-painting, makehuman

Automatic weighting of parts of a jacket.
[image]
I have tried to associate the armature with the weight of the jacket, but the upper neckline of the jacket, which is associated with the data that has hair bones, moves strangely.
How do I select the entire body in Transfer Weights and transfer it to the jacket?

[image]
But it goes funny in a different way. The clothes move strangely, the back is empty and the collar neck also moves strangely.
When I associate the hair bone in Vroid to the jacket, it becomes strange. If it is automatic weighting with no bones, it will not deform and looks good.
It looks like the hair armature is affecting the top of the clothing.

I tried using weight paint on the collar and neck, but it hardened and made the shape even stranger.
I tried to SOLIDIFY the clothes with thickness to prevent deformation, but it did not work.

Maybe Body and hair bone same group.
I can't separate.
If it can separate.
If I can use auto weight for body bone.
It can repair.
How to separate?
I want to apply the armature of the jacket only to the armature of the body.
[image]
Sorry I can not display my model.
I disappear my model.
Only function.
Thank you in advance.

After,
I tried belong.

I separate hair and body parent born `. I related only body born with a cloth. After that, I want to repair parents. I select hair born in edit mode. after, I shift select body born and ctrl P. like photo.
[image]

but It couldn&t choose connected.enter image description here How do select born is collect? And how to connect again? enter image description here It is collect relate.[image]

Comment: i am sorry, but i can only see white....

Comment: Sorry, I can't upload my model photo .
So I delete to use of white paint.
But I could upload bone armature photo and add text.

Comment: select all hair bones you don't want to affect the body, hold the Alt button and uncheck the "deform" bone option, perform the automatic weight painting, then turn on "deform" again

I tried it.
1. I select bone at obj mode.
2. I select all hair bones at edit mode and uncheck.
3. I select cloth and bone. and add auto weight.
4.  I select all hair bones at edit mode and check again.

but It still relating hair bone.
What is different?

And When I select.
 I can't use the alt key.
I could select not to use it.

Comment: 3.Select all hair bones, invert the selection, in obj mode shift select the character, go to weight paint mode, weight menu, choose "Assign automatic from bones".

I tried it.
But If it selects born and cloth.
It can not go weight mode.
If I select only cloth.
I can't choose Assign automatic from bones.
The font becomes gray.

Comment: select all vertices of the body, select one by one all vertex groups named as the hair bones and click on the "Remove" button.
I can do the this way.
  @josh sanfelici Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, some of them:

- select all hair bones you don't want to affect the body, hold the Alt button and uncheck the "deform" bone option, perform the automatic weight painting, then turn on "deform" again
- select all hair bones you don't want to affect the body, press P to separate them into another armature object, perform the weighting, rejoin with CtrlJ
- select all vertices of the body, select one by one all vertex groups named as the hair bones and click on the "Remove" button.
- Select all hair bones, invert the selection, in obj mode shift select the character, go to weight paint mode, weight menu, choose "Assign automatic from bones".

Anyway, when the deformations are difficult, some manual weight painting is required.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.
I'm trying two answers.
2. select all hair bones you don't want to affect the body, press P to separate them into another armature object, perform the weighting, rejoin with CtrlJ
I tried it to separate.
Body bone and heair bone connected dotted line,
I tried to rejoin but the border relationship doesn't repair.

Comment: 4.Select all hair bones, invert the selection, in obj mode shift select the character, go to weight paint mode, weight menu, choose "Assign automatic from bones".


I tried to select and invert to select mode.
But when I changed object mode.
Can't select only invert.
every selected.
Can I select only hair bone at object mode?
How to do it?

Comment: 3.select all vertices of the body, select one by one all vertex groups named as the hair bones and click on the "Remove" button.

Is it mean to select a naked body object at edit mode?
Doesn't it include clothes parts?
I tried to select all I tems.
I watch object Item properties at Vertex Groups.
But It didn't appear bone item.
Is it other menu or layer?
Where is it.
Sorry.
I'm beginner.

Comment: I udpated the answer with a screenshot, the first option is the simpler. 2 To repair the relationship between rigs go to edit mode, select the child bones, Shift select the parent bone (has to be last selected), press Ctrl P > Keep offset. 4 When you change to object mode, not-hair bones remain selected, even if you don't see them. 3 Vetrtex groups and bones are related when they share the same exact name, so editing the "Neck" vertex group will affect "Neck" bone behaviour.

Comment: @abc Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum, the answer section is reserved exclusively for answering the OP question, to post comments or replies please use the comments section instead. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).